# How to write the functional form of multivariate polynomial cubic spline?

Tags: multiple-regression, splines, interpolation

I got some articles/books about the cubic splines. However, I didn't see anyone mentioning the bivariate case of cubic spline much in detail. My question is how to write the cubic spline in a bivariate case with knots?

I am trying to perform the multiple linear regression with two regressors x and y, and 1 predicted variable z = f(x,y).

Comment: You're interested in regression, not interpolation, right?

Comment: @DeltalV Yes. Piecewise polynomial regression using spline basis functions.Basically on an image. x and y are the rows and columns and z is the intensity values.

Comment: Then just use tensor product splines. [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/254542/surface-fit-using-tensor-product-of-b-splines) is a fully worked out example. The answer uses `ginv`, which is not the best choice (`qr` would be more appropriate), but in practice unless you have a lot of data, or the condition number of `X` is large (in which case the condition number of `t(X) %*% X` will be quadratically as large), you shouldn't have problems.

Comment: I was considering csaps for the surface fit. I tried thin plate spline but my rows and columns are of different scale so I couldn't use it in Matlab as they need to be same for thin plate spline. I am interested in using interpolation as well if that is giving a good estimation of the intensity distribution of grayscale image

Comment: If this is an implementation-specific question, then it's not a good fit for CV: it would be better suited for SO. Anyway, did you read [this?](https://it.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/examples/bivariate-tensor-product-splines.html)

Comment: Thanks. I will look into it. The question I asked came to my mind while I was reading about bivariate splines.That's why I want to know how does the formal equation of cubic spline look like in the bivariate case. What about the coefficients?

Comment: The coefficients of the splines in the $x-$ direction are just splines in the $y-$ direction. That's all the concept behind tensor product splines. If you can write the equations for 1D splines, using this apporach you can write the equations for 2D splines yourself. Otherwise, read [this](http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/ifi/INF-MAT5340/v07/undervisningsmateriale/kap7.pdf).

Comment: So I implemented tensor product spline and csaps. tensor product spline: in comparison to csaps low adjusted R2 / less time / for higher degrees introduces haloing effect around objects. My main reason to use csaps was to reduce the degree of polynomial. But if I end up using higher degree in tensor product spline I can not use it. It is better to use polynomial regression instead.