# Using a spatial tensor spline in a nnet:multinom multinomial fit in R

Tags: generalized-additive-model, mgcv, multinomial-logit, nnet

I know that in `library(mgcv)` one can use spatial tensor spline smooths in `gam` fits with a cyclical spline basis for longitude as in

```
library(mgcv)
fit = gam(y ~ te(longitude, latitude, bs=c("cc","cs")), ...)
```

`library(splines2)` also has cyclical M splines, with which I thought I could use

```
mSpline(latitude, df=6, Boundary.knots=c(-90, 90), periodic=FALSE)
mSpline(longitude, df=6, Boundary.knots=c(-180, 180), periodic=TRUE)
```

in model formulas in other packages.

I now wanted to use a spatial 2D smooth in function of latitude and longitude in a `nnet::multinom` fit. I was wondering what would be the closest analog though of the above GAM tensor spline in function of latitude & longitude?

Would it be

```
library(nnet)
fit = multinom(VARIANT ~ mSpline(latitude, df=6, Boundary.knots=c(-90, 90), periodic=FALSE) :
  mSpline(longitude, df=6, Boundary.knots=c(-180, 180), periodic=TRUE),
                           weights=Freq, data=data)
```

(from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41623214/multivariate-regression-splines-in-r I gather this should produce row-wise Kronecker product between the two univariate spline basis matrices, which I think should produce a tensor spline fit then)

(I do know that GAM also supports multinomial in principle and it also has splines on a sphere, which could be better, but I have the problem that it doesn't support frequency weights, and requires data to be entered in long format, and my file is too large to be able to do that, [How to use frequency weights in an mgcv multinomial GAM fit in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/561571/how-to-use-frequency-weights-in-an-mgcv-multinomial-gam-fit-in-r); I also saw [Surface Fit Using Tensor Product of B-Splines](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/254542/surface-fit-using-tensor-product-of-b-splines), which provides some background on how to set up the tensor product, but I think the syntax above would achieve that).

An additional complexity is that I also have time in my model but my initial idea would be to just add an additive `ns(time, df=2)` term for that. Advice on how to code it as a 3D tensor spline, equivalent to `te(longitude, latitude, time, bs=c("cc","cs","cs"))` or `te(longitude,latitude, bs=c("cc","cs"))+s(time)+ ti(longitude, latitude, time, d=c(2,1), bs=c("cc","cs","cs"))`, but in `nnet::multinom` would be cool though (the `d=c(2,1)` argument here tells the
function that the smooth should consist of a tensor product between a
2-dimensional smooth (lat-long) and a 1-dimensional term (time)). Would the correct syntax to get something like this a term `(mSpline(latitude, df=5, Boundary.knots=c(-90, 90), periodic=FALSE): mSpline(longitude, df=5, Boundary.knots=c(-180, 180), periodic=TRUE)) : ns(date_num, df=2)` ?

EDIT: To give a bit more background on the specific problem I was working on: it concerns modelling the change in SARS-CoV2 lineage frequencies through time & space (my dataset uses latitudes & longitudes of the centroid of countries across the globe). Here is what I did right now - any feedback on whether this would make sense would be welcome:

```
library(nnet)
library(splines)
library(splines2)

VARIANT_levels = c("Other", "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta", "Omicron")
GISAID_ftable = read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/g9fhnw28vyarhdi/GISAID_freq_VARIANT_byweek_country.csv?dl=1") # dataset with lineage frequencies
GISAID_ftable$VARIANT = factor(GISAID_ftable$VARIANT, levels=VARIANT_levels)
countries_levels = sort(unique(GISAID_ftable$country))
continents_levels = sort(unique(GISAID_ftable$continent))
GISAID_ftable$country = factor(GISAID_ftable$country, levels=countries_levels)
GISAID_ftable$continent = factor(GISAID_ftable$continent, levels=continents_levels)
GISAID_ftable$week_midpoint = as.Date(GISAID_ftable$week_midpoint)
GISAID_ftable$date = GISAID_ftable$week_midpoint

set.seed(1)
fit1 = nnet::multinom(VARIANT ~ country + continent * ns(date_num, df=2) + 
                         mSpline(latitude, df=15, Boundary.knots=c(-90, 90), periodic=FALSE) : 
                         mSpline(longitude, df=15, Boundary.knots=c(-180, 180), periodic=TRUE), 
                       weights=Freq, data=GISAID_ftable, maxit=10000, MaxNWts=10000) # with spline ifo lat x long
fit2 = nnet::multinom(VARIANT ~ country + continent + 
                        (mSpline(latitude, df=5, Boundary.knots=c(-90, 90), periodic=FALSE) : 
                        mSpline(longitude, df=5, Boundary.knots=c(-180, 180), periodic=TRUE)) : 
                        ns(date_num, df=2), 
                      weights=Freq, data=GISAID_ftable, maxit=10000, MaxNWts=10000) # with spline ifo lat x long and time
```

Comment: The answer depends on what you need to accomplish and the spatial extent of your model.  For covering the entire earth, using a basis of spherical harmonics is one (fairly standard) solution.  Using a tensor spline to intertwine space and time would be strange: it's hard to imagine a phenomenon that wouldn't benefit from a more explicit spatio-temporal model.  These questions suggest that you include a little more contextual detail in your post.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the feedback! My dataset has latitudes & longitudes of the centroids of countries that span the entire globe. I've added a reproducible example now of the specific problem I was working on - comments welcome!

Comment: A suitable conception of "space" would incorporate a metric related to the ease or time of transmission of the virus.  This suggests (1) there's no need to model polar regions accurately; (2) the metric might vary a huge amount relative to the usual spherical distance.  Moreover, locating countries at their centroids reflects a gross approximation in the first place. Accordingly, there's probably no reason to pay much attention to the special nature of latitude and longitude *except* to make sure longitude is treated as a circular variable.

Comment: @whuber Yeah, the role of the additive spatial term in fit1 mSpline(latitude, df=10, Boundary.knots=c(-90, 90), periodic=TRUE):mSpline(longitude, df=10, Boundary.knots=c(-180, 180), periodic=TRUE) (on top of country) was mainly to avoid the model overfitting data from particular individual countries with limited data (perhaps using a multinomial glmnet with some elastic net regularisation could achieve that too). I also fitted the same model with country ommitted, which I would like to use to be able to interpolate & get estimates for other countries that are not in the dataset.

Comment: @whuber The multinomial logistic regression slopes are quite consistent across countries, as the advantage of one variant over another is an intrinsic property of the virus (it's the selection coefficient, https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.abg3055) (I now just allow the slopes to be different in different continents). The spatial tensor spline would merely be needed to model the different arrival times of each variant in each country & continent, in function of latitude & longitude. Some dynamic model incorporating spatial connectivity could work better for making future predictions.

Comment: @whuber My main question is whether that spatial term mSpline(latitude, df=10, Boundary.knots=c(-90, 90), periodic=TRUE):mSpline(longitude, df=10, Boundary.knots=c(-180, 180), periodic=TRUE) in my model would be correct in this case?

Comment: I don't understand what you might mean by "correct."  However, you definitely don't want to use a periodic spline for latitude!  That would place the North and South poles at the same location.

Comment: @whuber Well, I mean if this would be a sensible model to incoporate space. But yes, thanks - of course I should set periodic to FALSE for latitude then! (Visually the fit looked quite OK, I was just wondering if this was an accepted way to model spatial data if the latitude & longitude effect are not additive)

Comment: The fit likely looked OK because there's nothing going on near the poles.  It is obvious that latitude and longitude will not have an additive effect--that's one implication of my first comment--but that's not really a relevant question here.  What matters is whether including these coordinates using splines is helpful for your analysis.  That's not something we can provide objective opinions about without seeing (too many) details.

Comment: @whuber I refitted my models now (after fixing latitude to be nonperiodic) & compared the BIC of models and a per-continent spatial model fit = nnet::multinom(VARIANT ~ country + continent * ns(date_num, df=2) + mSpline(latitude, df=15, Boundary.knots=c(-90, 90), periodic=FALSE) : mSpline(longitude, df=15, Boundary.knots=c(-180, 180), periodic=TRUE), weights=Freq, data=GISAID_ftable, maxit=10000, MaxNWts=10000) was indeed better than one with the spatial component removed. So I guess that means this model shouldn't be too crazy then? A model with country removed also performed quite well.